# how to copy static uploaded input data to another upload input data in the same html page for firefox

Tags: javascript, file-upload

i am trying to upload a file and copy the uploaded data to a upload input button

```
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<input type="file" id="myFile1">
<script>
    var control = document.getElementById("myFile");
    control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {  
        var i = 0, files = control.files;
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
        var control1 = document.getElementById("myFile1");
        var i = 0;
        control1.files = control.files;     
        alert(document.getElementById("myFile1").files[0].name);
    }, false);
</script>
```

the above scenario seems to work in chrome but it's not working in firefox and ie

Comment: what error, if any, you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById("myFile1").files[0] is undefined